# Basic app not working in Web after changing App.js to App/index.js

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm new to React Native and tried to follow the lesson "[Organize a React Native Project](https://learn.reactnativeschool.com/courses/175915/lectures/17152118)" so I moved the code from `App.js` to `App/index.js` and deleted `App.js`. That works fine in the Android simulator but not in the Web browser.

There I get this error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `ExpoRootComponent`.
▶ 24 stack frames were collapsed.
registerRootComponent
C:/Users/me/Documents/src/launch/registerRootComponent.web.tsx:14
  11 |   const RootComponent: React.FC<P> = props => <App {...props} />;
  12 |   AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => RootComponent);
  13 |   const rootTag = document.getElementById('root') ?? document.getElementById('main');
> 14 |   AppRegistry.runApplication('main', { rootTag });
  15 | }
```

My app code is really simple, it is the default one from the Expo basic template. `index.js` :

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I have run the commands `expo start` and `npm start` but no difference.

Provide (the default) `AppEntry.js` in case it is of interest:

```
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';

import App from '../../App';

registerRootComponent(App);
```

Comment: Does it work if you change the AppEntry import to be `import App from '../../App/index'`? I'm not very familiar with RN but they could be ignoring the default behavior introduced by Node where `index` serves as the entry point for a directory.

Comment: changing the `./node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js` import to `import App from '../../App/index';` instead of `import App from '../../App';` will work for you. but generally it is not recommended to edit the `./node_modules` files.

Comment: That worked thanks! So instead you recommend to keep both files? In that case, what should I put in `App.js`? (As my "landing page" will be in `App/index.js`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `package.json` file to have the `main` property as follows.

```
  "main": "YourFilePath/YourEntryFile.js"
```

in your case `"main": "App/index.js",`

and in the component that you want to make the root component,

Class-based component `YourEntryFile.js`

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <View />;
  }
}

registerRootComponent(App); //this is important
```

Functional component `YourEntryFile.js`

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});

registerRootComponent(App) //This line is important
```

[Please refer to expo docs for more info](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/#what-if-i-want-to-name-my)

Comment: One small addition is required to the code above to avoid any errors:
`const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});`

Comment: :-) I forgot the style part